# Roadmap to the geometry of lie groups and Duistermaat ideas.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

I'm currently an advanced undergrad studentwith interest in differential geometry and topology, but this term I took a lie groups class and it was fascinating, nevertheless, there seems to be a break in the theory at some point: You either study the algebra o the group of you study the geometry of the group.

Looking for further reading material I came across Duistermaat's book on Lie groups and it has alot of deatiled calculation that other books do not have (such as seeing the flow in the fréchet sense and proving conditions for those terribly abstract differential equations)but there seems to be a gap. That is certainly not an introductory book or even for a second course but more as an advanced book on the geometry of lie groups.

So, are there any other nice references that deal with the geometric part of lie groups?

(I am particualry interested in looking for a roadmap that let's me deal with geometric flows on lie groups such as ricci flow, mean curvature flow and harmonic functional on lie groups such as the area functional, and so on)

Thank you all for your time reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be not what you want.

I think it's a dilemma: You want to study the geometry of lie group by staying a bit away from the algebra, but the geometry is interesting precisely because the algebra helps simplify the geometric problem/calculations.

My suggestion is that you either take a standard course on Lie group or read a standard (not too long) book on Lie group (such as [this](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540136781) and [this](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781475740943)).

For the geometric side, it depends on which flows you are working on. You might follow the suggestions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927642/which-is-the-best-book-for-studying-geometric-flows?rq=1) for Ricci flows and mean curvature flows.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your time. 

The thing is: I took a course on lie groups this term and found out that most of the topics (once the basics are covered) tend to focus in the way we can use representation theory to study lie groups and lie algebras.
But there was no text (as far as I looked) that focused on the geometry of lie groups (besides Duistermaat's book) and no clear roadmap for that (knowing that my main interest right now is to study geometric flows).

But thank you very much for your answer, I'll take a look to the question you linked.